# Why are my social media font awesome icons appearing as empty squares on homepage?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The problem only appears on my homepage. On the other pages it works fine. My site is https://www.eviakussens.nl. The social media icons are in the footer. I have been struggling for some hours now to try and fix it, but I'm unable to find the issue. I probably think something is overwriting the CSS code of these elements, but I can't find what's causing this. Who knows what's causing this and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and revise your question.

Answer (score 0):

On homepage you have your `font-family` set to `"Font Awesome 5 Free"`, but on other pages it is set to `FontAwesome`.
So apply the desirable `font-family` to your icons:

```
.home .fa, .home .fas {
font-family: FontAwesome!important;
}
```